# I have a small hand and am an adult. Would 1/2 or 3/4 classical guitar be ok?

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar, physical-limitations, ergonomics

I have a small hand, and classical pieces sometimes require wide stretches.

I am considering buying smaller guitar, but wouldn't it compromise playing quality?

If not, is an adult using 1/2 or 3/4, or even 1/4 as a main instrument a common thing?

Comment: Uh, this might be difficult to answer. Note that small instruments are made for children, who have not only small hands, but also arms and rest of their bodies.

Comment: It works for [Ed Sheeran](https://guitargearfinder.com/guides/ed-sheeran-guitar-rig/).

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that those sizes are not really representative. A 3/4 guitar isn't actually 3/4 the size of a full sized guitar, for example. It's more like 7/8.

As a beginner, you *could* buy a smaller guitar - asking a teacher, or the seller in the music shop, would be a better bet that trying to get answers from complete strangers who haven't even seen you.

But, for at least a couple of years, you're not going to try playing any pieces with wide stretches, and by that time, you'll have got used to playing a full sized guitar, with a better sound than its smaller siblings, and found strategies for finding your way round.

There's also the argument that crops up from time to time - being used to playing a smaller guitar, and someone thrusts the far more common full sized at you. It's going to sound lame to say 'I can only play a little one!', isn't it?

Sure, you'll get by, but there are other factors to consider with smaller hands - the width of the fingerboard, the profile of the neck, for example. There is probably a full sized guitar out there with the right combination of other factors. Go and search!

For several years, though, I used a parlour acoustic guitar (around 60 yrs old) during lessons I was giving, while gigging with a full sized electric whenever needed. I never ever felt that one was substantially different from the other, as far as fret size was concerned. It had (still has!) a scale of 24" as opposed to that of a standard guitar ~25.5". Making the fret differences themselves hardly worth discussing. The body was *much* smaller though.